# Printing value in each bin in hist2d (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to create a 2d histogram, where in each bin the value represented by that bin is shown in the center of that given bin. For example a `hist2d` of size 5x5 would have 25 values inside the final graph. This is well doable with PyROOT, but I need to use matplotlib/pyplot here.

The following has been tried according to the first answer:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
hist, xbins, ybins, im = ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=(4, [1,2,3,5,10,20]))
ax.text(xbins[1]+0.5,ybins[1]+0.5, "HA", color="w", ha="center", va="center", fontweight="bold")

img = StringIO.StringIO()
plt.savefig(img, format='svg')
img.seek(0)
print("%html <div style='width:500px'>" + img.getvalue() + "</div>")
```

There wasn't any error message but "HA" wan't displayed in the first bin at all. I am programming this in Zeppelin, thus I need to take img from buffer ...

Comment: Can you use [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/heatmap_annotation.html)?

Comment: With bins defined in this way I achieved non-constant intervals of bins. And this works quite fine. It means that e.g. third bin in y-direction takes range 3-5.

Comment: seaborn could make a job, apart from non-constant binning.

Answer (score 9):

To annotate a `hist2d` plot, just like any other plot, you may use matplotlib's `text` method. The values to annotate are given by the returned histogram. The positions of the annotations are given by the histogram edges (plus half the bin width). You may then loop over all bins and place a text in each bin.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.poisson(size=(160))
y = np.random.poisson(size=(160))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
hist, xbins, ybins, im = ax.hist2d(x,y, bins=range(6))

for i in range(len(ybins)-1):
    for j in range(len(xbins)-1):
        ax.text(xbins[j]+0.5,ybins[i]+0.5, hist.T[i,j], 
                color="w", ha="center", va="center", fontweight="bold")

plt.show()
```

[image]

If only a single annotation is required, e.g. the following

```
ax.text(xbins[1]+0.5,ybins[1]+0.5, "HA", 
        color="w", ha="center", va="center", fontweight="bold")
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer to include printing of a single label.

Comment: I think the indexes for the hist array in the loop are inverted. It is difficult to notice because values are not so different in the matrix but the 32 cell should have a lighter color and the 25 one a darker one.